# Which filesystem to use when a samba share should allow for NTFS encryption?

Tags: samba, encryption, ntfs

I'm using a NAS ([Buffalo LinkStation Pro](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/network-storage/home-and-small-office-nas/linkstation-pro-duo-1) with SSH access, if that matters) which runs Linux (`2.6.31.8 #1 Fri Jun 8 11:07:30 JST 2012 armv5tel GNU/Linux`, with `smbd --version` = `Version 3.0.30-1.4.osstech`), while all clients run Windows 7. Currently, the shares are on a xfs partition. How can samba be modified such that the share behaves like an NTFS share to the clients, i.e. allowing for encryption? Or do I need to reformat the partition as an NTFS drive (or more likely, use a loop-mounted NTFS file)?

Comment: Do you want the server or the client to do the encryption? If you want to do encryption in the Windows client, you're asking on the wrong site: flag to have your question migrated to [su].

Comment: @Gilles I'd prefer if the client did the actual encryption. But what I'm asking for is how (if possible) to set up samba (or whatever else is required on a Linux server) such that a network share will be treated with EFS support. It's a question about a Linux server interacting with Windows clients, so if the question is off-topic here, I'd rather have it migrated to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). But since the ideal solution would simple have the NAS share look like a true Windows machine share, it is a *nix question IMHO

Comment: @Gilles ... However, I may have asked the wrong question. [How to set up an encrypted directory to be mounted only during samba access?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50550/863) is maybe a better idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Samba share can *never* behave as a NTFS share, *only* as a SMB/CIFS share. If you want encryption then you will need to use a per-file/directory tool, or implement it in the server instead.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to have the NAS share files that are en-/decrypted transparently on the client side?

Comment: The NAS will share whatever files you like, but the transparency must be handled by the client unless you, again, implement it in the server.

Comment: And can't NTFS do exactly that, and the NAS would simply store the encrypted data more or less without knowing it's encrypted?

Comment: Yes. But **you can't use NTFS over SMB**.

Comment: I see :-/ So the only way to have transparent client-side encryption is via some third-party software? Can't I share like another Windows PC does, where encryption is possible?